# Validate Android String Resource HTML

Tags: java, android, html, validation

I am creating an app that allows you to edit Android String Resources.  Sometimes resources contain HTML tags.

```
<string name="foo"><b>foo</b></string>
<string name="bar">bar <i>baz</i></string>
```

The entire text with the raw HTML should be editable.  I want to have a validation that ensures the output string has the same set of tags as the original and that they are all closed correctly.

I am looking for a clever way to do this.  I am open to any Java library that will run on Android that does HTML validation.